# Finding anagram

Tags: c, string, anagram

```
if (strlen(a) != strlen(b)) {
    printf("Not anagram");
} else {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(b); j++) {
            if (a[i] == b[j]) {
                len++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (len != strlen(a))
        printf("Not anagram");
    else
        printf("Anagram");
}
return 0;
```

This is a code snippet to check if 2 strings are anagrams. How can repeated characters be handled here? Also, could this program be made more optimized? And what would be the runtime complexity of this code?

Comment: Is this really Objective-C? Looks more like a pure C.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the tag.

Comment: I think that a better algorithm would be to sort the letters in both words alphabetically and them compare them for equality.

Comment: Your approach would normally be O(n^2) where *n* is the length of each string.  However, your implementation is O(n^3) since you recompute `strlen` on *each* iteration.  If you went with a sorting approach, you could do it O(n log n) or O(n) time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An optimal solution would be probably based on calculating the number of characters in every string and then comparing both counts. Ideally, we should use a *Dictionary* data structure but for simplicity, I will demonstrate the algorithm on an array:

```
char *word1 = "word1";
char *word2 = "ordw1";

// C strings can have only 256 possible characters, therefore let's store counts in an array with 256 items.
int* letterCounts1 = calloc(256, sizeof(int));
int* letterCounts2 = calloc(256, sizeof(int));
size_t length1 = strlen(word1);
size_t length2 = strlen(word2);

for (size_t i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
    int letterIndex = word1[i] & 0xFF;
    letterCounts1[letterIndex] += 1;
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < length2; i++) {
    int letterIndex = word2[i] & 0xFF;
    letterCounts2[letterIndex] += 1;
}

bool isAnagram = true;

for (size_t i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    if (letterCounts1[i] != letterCounts2[i]) {
        isAnagram = false;
        break;
    }
}

free(letterCounts1);
free(letterCounts2);

if (isAnagram) {
    printf("Anagram");
} else {
    printf("Not anagram");
}
```

This algorithm has linear (`O(n)`) complexity (iteration over the "dictionary" can be considered a constant).

Your original solution has quadratic complexity, however, you would also have to make sure to store result of `strlen` into variables because every call to `strlen` has to iterate over the whole string, increasing complexity to cubic.

Comment: `letterCounts1` and `letterCounts2` should be `size_t *` to account for pathologically long strings with repeated characters.

Comment: @chqrlie You are probably right but these small issues probably won't be important to the OP. I only have rudimentary C knowledge anyway. Your solution will be better from C perspective.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this is not the right solution. Think in this 2 strings: "aabc" and "aade"
a[0] == b[0], a[0] == b[1], a[1] == b[0] and a[1] == b[1]. len would be 4 but they are not anagram. Complexity is O(n^2) being n the length of the string.

As @Sulthan has answered you, a better approach is to sort the strings which complexity is O(n*log(n)) and then compare both strings in one go O(n).

To order the strings in O(n * log(n)) you can not use a bubble method but you can use a merge-sort as described here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/

An even better approach is to create an array of integers in which you count the number of occurrences of each character in the first string and then you subtract one of the occurrences for each occurrence in the second array. In the end, all the positions of the auxiliary array must be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Here a some answers:

- Your algorithm does not handle duplicate letters, it may return false positives.
- It is unclear if it is correct otherwise because you did not post a complete function definition with all declarations and definitions, especially whether `len` is initialized to `0`.
- It has **O(N<sup>2</sup>)** time complexity or even **O(N<sup>3</sup>)** if the compiler cannot optimize the numerous redundant calls to `strlen()`.

Here is simple solution for systems with 8-bit characters with linear complexity:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int check_anagrams(const char *a, const char *b) {
    size_t counters[256];
    size_t len = strlen(a);
    size_t i;

    if (len != strlen(b)) {
        printf("Not anagrams\n");
        return 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        counters[i] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int c = (unsigned char)a[i];
        counters[c] += 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int c = (unsigned char)b[i];
        if (counters[c] == 0) {
            printf("Not anagrams\n");
            return 0;
        }
        counters[c] -= 1;
    }
    printf("Anagrams\n");
    return 1;
}
```